# Request body is missing in the server end for feign application/x-www-form-urlencoded type request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I have been working on building feign client to send a form urlencoded requests. The thing is it worked fine till yesterday without no issues. But now request body is not being sent to the server.

Here is my configuration.

```
    EmailClientConfiguration.class
    
    public class EmailClientConfiguration  {
        
        @Bean
        public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
            return template -> {
                 template.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            };
        }
        
        @Bean
        public OkHttpClient client() {
            return new OkHttpClient();
        }
        
        @Bean
        Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
            return Logger.Level.FULL;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public Decoder feignDecoder() {
            return new JacksonDecoder();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public Encoder feignFormEncoder () {
            return new SpringFormEncoder(new JacksonEncoder());
        }
    }
```

**Client:**

```
    @FeignClient(name = "email", url = "localhost:3000", 
        configuration = EmailClientConfiguration.class)
    public interface EmailClient {
    
        @PostMapping(value = "/email/send", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        ResponseDto sendEmail(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody);
        
    }
```

**Request Body:**

```
Map<String, String> requestBody = 
Map.of("username", "xyz",
"email", "xyz@gmail.com",
"key", "xxx");
```

I debugged from server end too can't find why request body is not received. I see no error while sending requests. How to check if request body present before sending requests.

Comment: You are using jackson encoder and decoder, it might be converting your params into json and hence params might not be reaching as form data, try commenting encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Feign Client when consuming `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` based API from Pinterest REST API.

Finally all the things were working with following setup, and here I've added Basic authentication to the Feign Client.

This client communication layer was developed with

- spring boot 2.6.0
- feign-form 3.8.0
- feign-form-spring 3.8.0
- feign-core 11.7

```java
package com.javatodev.app.openfeignposttest.rest.client;

import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@FeignClient(name = "pinterest-api-request-client", url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v5", configuration = PinterestAPIClient.Configuration.class)
public interface PinterestApiRequestClient {

    @PostMapping(path = "/oauth/token", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    PinterestAccessTokenResponse getAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody PinterestAccessTokenRequest request);

    class Configuration {

@Bean
        public Encoder feignFormEncoder () {
            return new SpringFormEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
            return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("app_id", "app_secret");
        }
    }
}
```

Request and Response DTOs

```
package com.javatodev.app.openfeignposttest.rest.client;

import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PinterestAccessTokenRequest {
    private String code;
    private String redirect_uri;
    private String grant_type;
}
```

```
package com.javatodev.app.openfeignposttest.rest.client;

import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PinterestAccessTokenResponse {

    private String access_token;
    private String refresh_token;
    private String response_type;
    private Long expires_in;
    private Long refresh_token_expires_in;
    private String scope;

}
```